# Universal ctags with emacs

Tags: emacs, global, ctags

Sorry I am trying to configure ctags with emacs but I am in trouble.

I compiled global with this configure:

```
./configure --with-universal-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
```

and I executed `make && make install`.
Then I changed the default target in the file .globalrc from *native* to *new-ctags*.
Finally I executed `ggtags-create-tags` within emacs.
Unfortunately I got the error

```
‘gtags’ non-zero exit: gtags: execvp failed.
 gtags: unexpected EOF.
```

Can anyone help me, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) is as simple as:

1. Run over a project *(`-R` is to walk the project recursively, and `-e` is to use Emacs-compatible syntax)*:

   ```
   $ ctags -eR
   ```

   **Alternatively** if you like to only include files with certain extensions, you can use `-a` *(append, creates a file if doesn't exist)* option with `find` utility, like:

   ```
   $ find -name "*.cpp" -print -or -name "*.h" -print -or -name "*.hxx" -print -or -name "*.cxx" -print | xargs ctags -ea
   ```
2. Run <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>visit-tags-table</kbd> in Emacs, and navigate to the created TAGS file.